# Toolbar does not scale correctly in E4

Tags: eclipse-rcp, scaling, e4

I have a E4 application with some custom toolbar widgets. When the application ran in WIndows 10 without DPI scaling, everything looks fine. After chaning the DPI settings the application toolbar is not fully viewed.

Correct view:

[image]

With scaling enabled:

[image]

The application.e4xmi looks like:
[image]

The class that is responsible for creating the widget looks like:

```java
public class OpenOrderDropDown {

  @Inject
  private IEclipseContext context;

  private Combo combo;

  private static final String[] ITEMS = {"Default", "Planning", "Open JobOrders", "Stock Units", "To Schedule"};

  @PostConstruct
  public void createControls(final Composite parent) {

    RowLayout layout = new RowLayout();
    parent.setLayout(layout);

    Label label = new Label(parent, SWT.LEFT);
    label.setText("View: ");

    combo = new Combo(parent, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.READ_ONLY);
    combo.setItems(ITEMS);

    combo.select(0);

    combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

        IEventBroker eventBroker = context.get(IEventBroker.class);
        eventBroker.post("openOrdersView", combo.getText());

      }
    });
  }

  @Inject
  @Optional
  public void changeSelection(@UIEventTopic("changeOpenOrdersView") String selection) {
    if (selection == null || selection.isEmpty()) {
      selection = "Default";
    }

    if (combo != null && !combo.isDisposed()) {
      combo.select(combo.indexOf(selection));
    }

  }

}
```

Is there some way to change the heigt of the widgets in the toolbar? I know how to calculate the DPI change but cannot set any heigt/width values on any of the components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the ToolControl items to be outside of the ToolBar. Controls inside a ToolBar don't resize the bar but when outside of the ToolBar they should resize the TrimBar ok.

Comment: Ok the scaling is working now. But the layout of my toolbar is crap now. Is there a way to add a gridlayout or rowlayout to the trimbar?

Comment: What does 'crap' mean? Probably best to ask a new question showing what you see

Comment: All tool controls are located under each other instead of next to each other. In other words only the top most control is viewed, the others are not viewable because they are under the top one.

Comment: This is probably because you are setting RowLayout on the `parent` composite - that composite does not belong to your code and you should not be touching it. Create a new Composite as a child of the parent to hold your controls, do not set a layout on the parent.