# Add custom toolcontrol to toolbar E4

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

Currently my custom toolcontrols are outside the toolbars because of the scaling issue in E4. [Toolbar does not scale correctly in E4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280425/toolbar-does-not-scale-correctly-in-e4)

Now my client want to have different toolbars for all the toolcontrols, so that the user can rearange the order of the toolbar and separate the toolcontrols from each others. How is this possible in E4? I know the toolcontrols inside the toolbar is not scaling the toolbar itself. But is there any workaround to place a toolcontrol inside a toolbar?

Comment: Maybe using large images for the tool items in the tool bar will make it large enough for the controls (or a large font if the tool items are text).

Comment: When I add a icon to the toolbar it does scale correctly. Is there some way to render the icon but make it not visible to the user? In this way we can make it work and trick Eclipse for scaling the toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added ahidden icon to the toolbar when adding the custom toolcontrol to it. Eclipse scales the toolbar correct know.